# Symfony2: serve file download with flash message

Tags: symfony, download, flash-message

In my symfony2 app, I allow users download some files:

```
class FileController extends Controller
{
     ...

     public function downloadFilesAction()
     {
        //This will serve a page listing all downloadable files and their url

     }

     public function downloadFileAction($file_id)
     {
         //This will be requested from the page served 
         //in the above "downloadFilesAction()"

         try {
             // Some processing goes here ...
         }
         catch (\Exception $e) 
         {
             $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'Error occurred');
             return $this->forward('MyBundle:File:downloadFiles');
         }

         //get file content into &content variable

         $headers = array(
             'Content-Type' => 'text/csv;',
             'Content-Disposition' => "attachment; filename*=UTF-8''downloadedfile.csv",
         ); 

         return new Response($content, 200, $headers);
     }
}
```

Let's assume the first time there was an error and flash error message was shown; and the second time download succeeded. The problem is at the second request flash message still stay on the page. How can I get rid of the flash message when download succeeded?

Answer (score 0):

Just clear the flashbag's existing message using `get('error')` inside your `downloadFileAction()` first.

Note that using `FlashBag->clear()` would unset all messages (which isn't needed).

```
public function downloadFileAction($file_id)
{
    $flashBag = $this->get('session')->getFlashBag();
    $flashBag->get('error'); // clear the error message

    try {
         // ...
    }
    catch (\Exception $e) 
    {
        $flashBag->add('error', 'Error occurred');

        return $this->forward('MyBundle:File:downloadFiles');
    }

    // ...
```

Comment: Well, I copy&pasted your suggested code, and it didn't work. The problem is, when download succeeds, browser displays file download dialog, and the original page isn't refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

To reset the flash bag you can redirect users instead of forwarding an action :

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('download_files_route'));
```